# AWS Cost Explorer - stopping s3 reports

Tags: amazon-web-services, cost-management

I enabled reporting from AWS Cost Explorer to an S3 bucket to test spot.io. I am being charged about $6.50 a month in API requests to Cost Explorer. I would like to turn off this feature so that I am no longer charged. Does anyone have any ideas on how to turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the way that spot.io interacts with your account for Cost Explorer API access is through a cross account IAM role that is typically named either "*CloudAnalyzerRoleArn*" or "*SpotnistRoleArn*".

From the IAM dashboard you should be able to find the role to either **(1)** remove the cost explorer permissions (prefaced with "ce:") from it or **(2)** delete the role. The latter approach may impact your ability to fully connect with Spot.io services at all though.

Lastly, the fact that spot.io is costing you `$6.50 per month` in API calls is pretty steep. These API calls are priced at `$0.01` each so it means Spot.io is making a lot of calls to this service. An alternative that charges significantly less than this is Vantage which can be found at https://vantage.sh